# A table has two links to another table. How does .Include specify one of those links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

tblWorkOrder has two links to tblUser through tblWorkOrder.EnteredBy and tblWorkorder.ClosedBy.  The code below selects the ClosedBy link. How do I specify the OpenedBy link?

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnteredBy()
{
    using (var context = new FacilityEntities())
    {
        List<SelectListItem> user = context.tblWorkOrder.AsNoTracking().Include("tblUser")
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.tblUser.LastName, x.tblUser.FirstName, x.tblUser.UserID })
            .Select(x =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Key.UserID,
                Text = string.Concat(x.Key.FirstName, " ", x.Key.LastName)
            }).ToList();
        var usertip = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = null,
            Text = "Select"
        };
        user.Insert(0, usertip);
        return new SelectList(user, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relationship in your Entity, use `ForeignKey` attribute to explicitly define which foreign key is associated to which navigation property.

```
public class tblWorkOrder 
{
    public long? CloseById { get; set; } // ForeignKey
    [Foreignkey("CloseById")]  // CloseBy navigation property is associated to CloseById
    public tblUser CloseBy{ get; set; } // assuming tblUser is the name of your entity

    public long? EnteredById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EnteredById")]
    public tblUser EnteredBy { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Once you define your navigation property correctly, you can simply include them in the query:

```
context.tblWorkOrder.AsNoTracking().Include(r => r.CloseBy).Include(r => r.EnteredBy)
...
```

Comment: If your model was like this, then it should have worked... maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The model looked like this at first:
public partial class tblWorkOrder
...
public virtual tblUser {get; set;}
public virtual tblUser1 {get; set;}
...

I changed it to:
public int? CloseByID {get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CloseByID")]
public virtual tbluser CloseBy { get; set; }
public int? OpenByID {get; set; }
[ForeignKey("OpenByID")]
public virtual tbluser OpenBy { get; set; }

I tried this:
List<SelectListItem> user = context.tblWorkOrder.AsNoTracking().Include(r => r.EnterBy)
but got error:
Cannot convert lambda espression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: So I changed it to:
List<SelectListItem> user = context.tblWorkOrder.AsNoTracking().Include("EnterBy")
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Enterby.Firstname, x.Enterby.Lastname, x.EnterBy.UserID})
...

That compiles, but I get this runtime error:
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
The relationship 'FacilityModel.FK_tblWorkOrder_tblCivilEngineering' was not loaded
because the type. 'FacilityModel.tblWorkOrder' is ot available.

Comment: I am sorry but it is really hard to read your code in the comment, this should be inside the question where other people could read it easily. If you want some help with your original model, I suggest asking a new question and describing the problem.